# Implicit awaiting?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method `Create` :

```
public async Task<MyObject> Create(string str1, string str2)
{
    // Check to see if a MyObject can be created in the database.
    if (!await CanCreate(str1, str2))
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Create the object.
    var myObj = new MyObject
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now.Date,
        First = str1,
        Second = str2
    };

    // Log this event.
    _loggingService.Log(myObj, LogType.Created);

    // Return the created MyObject.
    return _repository.CreateAsync(myObj));
}
```

The method `CanCreate(string, string)` returns a `Task<bool>`.

The method `Log(MyObject, LogType)` returns a `Task`.

The method `CreateAsync(MyObject)` returns a `Task<MyObject>`.

---

Notice that `CanCreate` is awaited while both `Log` and `CreateAsync` are not. My question is then, in my example, when `Create` returns and is awaited like so:

```
 var result = await _service.Create("abc", "def");
```

is `Log` also awaited by the await call on `Create`?

Comment: The answer is no. `Create` MAY complete before `_loggingService.Log(myObj, LogType.Created);` completes. Visual Studio should give you a warning about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is Log also awaited by the await call on Create?

No, it isn't. `Log` will pass through and the encapsulated task it produces will be ignored (along with any exception it propagates). Because you end up returning the task from `CreateAsync`, that will be awaited.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Log` method won't be awaited.

When you call an `async` method without an `await` keyword, what happens is that the method gets called but the original thread won't "wait" for it to complete. It is often referred as `fire and forget`.

Generally, it is better to `await` all `async` methods but it depends on a situation.